# Is there any good way to control the line just after manual indented line?

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I'd like to control an indent as follows:

```
#define MY_NS_MACRO namespace myns

namespace ns1 {
int a;  // indent 0 as expected
int b;  // indent 0 as expected
}

MY_NS_MACRO {
int c;  // indent 0 manually (If I press TAB here, indent 4)
 int d; // I expect indent 0, but indent 1...
}

void f() {
    int e = 0; // indent 4 as expected.
}
```

The variables a, b, and e are indented as expected. The variable c, emacs controls indent 4. However, I'd like to indent 0. So I remove four spaces by hand. It's OK for me. Then, I enter the next variable d, I expect the line is indented 0 too. However, it is indented 1. Is there any way to control the indent?

Here is my .emacs:

```
(defun my-c-c++-mode-init ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
  (c-set-offset 'innamespace 0)
  (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
  )
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-c++-mode-init)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c-c++-mode-init)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there's a variable that's interfering with what you want to do [c-label-minimum-indentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Other-Indentation.html)

If you set that like so:

```
(setq c-label-minimum-indentation 0)  ;# default is 1
```

You get the indentation you want.